# Get Deadlock when doing a HTTPRequest after catching WebserviceException

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, c#-4.0

I get somehow a Deadlock/hanging after I purposely catch a WebServiceException to let my application continue. However, even though the application contiues. Doing a webservice hangs and it probably seems like it is still trying to do something from the previous call.
I tried using CancellationTokenSource but that did not seem to solve my problem.

RetryHandler:

```
public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const int MaxRetries = 2;

    public RetryHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        Exception lastException = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxRetries; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lastException = ex;
            }

            if (IsSuccessful(response))
            {
                return response;
            }
        }

        throw GetException(response, lastException);
    }
```

Calling Post twice makes my program hang:

```
    public async Task<T> Post<T>(
        string path,
        HttpContent content,
        string username,
        string token,
        HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(handler));
        var authString = GetAuthenticationString(username, token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authString);
        AddUsernameAndTokenToClientRequestHeader(client, username, token);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

        var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(path), content, _cancelHttpRequests.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultContent);        
    }
```

Comment: That is strange... Should be hanging on *first call* to `.Result`. Check if you are not missing any steps.

Comment: What I want to do. is to catch the WebServiceException and then cancel the request so that it doesn't hang at all :O man this sucks :(

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is, **although you are catching the exception, and supposedly let your application continue, the service itself continues it's work, async, so that even when you are trying to force the service to continue, it will still go on attempting to complete all of the desired action.**

In your case: causing deadlock. Cancellation token won't help here, as your service running async and you already stopped it by catching the exception, so, you are basically doing nothing with this token.

Two ways to solve this:

Either, disconnect the service when you are getting the exception, this way forcing the service to shut.

Or try to work with your service in a sync way so that you can stop the service when ever needed, this way insuring it won't do any additional work when you stop it.

Comment: N00b question. do you have any code sample/known method to force the service to shut down?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop(v=vs.110).aspx

This is to stop all of the services, including the parent service.